# JQuery Sortable is expanding the width of my table cells

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have applied the sortable class to my table:

```
var $sortableList = $("#myTable");
$sortableList.sortable({ items: 'td', stop: sortEventHandler });
```

All works fine and dandy apart but when my td elements are clicked on the width now changes so they fill the row.

Anyone had an issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had an empty table cell at the end of my row. Sortable applies the class ui-sortable-handle to all td elements in the row then distributes the width to fill the row.

```
$('#EmptyCell').removeClass("ui-sortable-handle");
```

Removing the class like above for the td elements you don't want to include in the sort fixes it.